# multiple left join's issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT tblCompanies.*, users.Username, cargo.Name, (tblCompanies.Money + SUM(tblCTerminals.sellValue)) as assets, (COUNT(tblFinishedContracts.ID) + COUNT(tblFinishedSubContracts.ID)) as completed FROM ((((tblCompanies LEFT JOIN users ON tblCompanies.CompanyCEO = users.ID) LEFT JOIN cargo ON (tblCompanies.PreferredCargo = cargo.Cargo_ID)) LEFT JOIN tblCTerminals ON (tblCompanies.Company_ID = tblCTerminals.companyID)) LEFT JOIN tblFinishedContracts ON (tblCompanies.Company_ID = tblFinishedContracts.companyID)) LEFT JOIN tblFinishedSubContracts ON (tblCompanies.Company_ID = tblFinishedSubContracts.companyID) WHERE (users.Username LIKE :info || tblCompanies.CompanyName LIKE :info2 || CONCAT('$',FORMAT((tblCompanies.Money + SUM(tblCTerminals.sellValue)),2)) LIKE :info3 || CONCAT('$',FORMAT(tblCompanies.Money,2)) LIKE :info4 || cargo.Name LIKE :info5 || users.pLevel LIKE :info6 || CONCAT('$',FORMAT((users.Cash_In_Bank + users.Cash_In_Hand),2)) LIKE :info7)");

$sth->bindValue(':info', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':info2', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':info3', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':info4', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':info5', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':info6', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(':info7', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Ok so now my reasoning for this mess:

I'm using the [jQuery Datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin and when it does a request to the server it sends the query.  It expects back the results, how many results in the search query and how many total results.  With this query I can return the results.

However on COUNT(tblFinishedContracts.ID) it is grabbing the table 8 times.  So for example instead of returning the correct amount of 8 it is returning a count of 112.

When I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(tblFinishedContracts.ID) 
FROM tblCompanies 
LEFT JOIN tblFinishedContract 
     ON (tblCompanies.Company_ID = tblFinishedContracts.ID)     
WHERE tblCompanies.Company_ID = 11
```

It works, it returns 8.  If someone knows a better way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish or can tell me how to fix the issue, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Jeff

**EDIT:** to add, no columns have duplicate names everything is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single silver bullet for this issue; getting information about a parent table, while also getting information from multiple child tables with one-to-many relationships, is always tricky. But there are a few techniques that can help.

Firstly, you don't actually do anything with `tblFinishedContracts` except get a count of records from it; so instead of writing `COUNT(tblFinishedContracts.ID)` and using a join, you can use a subquery: write `(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblFinishedContracts WHERE Company_ID = tblCompanies.Company_ID)`. The same thing applies to `tblFinishedSubContracts`, so you can eliminate that join as well. (By the way, eliminating these joins should also improve your performance significantly, since you'll only need to retrieve information about contracts that belong to companies that are actually being returned.)

That takes care of *most* of the problem. The joins to `users` and `cargo` to get the CEO and preferred cargo shouldn't cause any problems. (Right?)

The only remaining difficulty is `tblCTerminals`, since `SUM(tblCTerminals.sellValue)` field occurs both in the field list and in the `WHERE` clause. There's no really compelling way to handle it. One option is to use the above-mentioned subquery approach, with two copies of the subquery. Another is to replace `FROM tblCompanies` with `FROM (SELECT tblCompanies.*, COALESCE(SUM(tblCTerminals.sellValue), 0) AS totalCTerminalSellValue FROM tblCompanies LEFT JOIN tblCTerminals ON tblCTerminals.Company_ID = tblCompanies.Company_ID GROUP BY tblCompanies.Company_ID) AS tblCompanies`, which in essence creates a temporary copy of `tblCompanies` that's augmented with a new field named `totalCTerminalSellValue`. So, elsewhere in the query, you can replace `SUM(tblCTerminals.sellValue)` with `tblCompanies.totalCTerminalSellValue`.

Comment: Ok so this is what I have now and I'm getting an error that says check  for correct syntax near "`SELECT 1 FROM tblFinishedSubContracts WHERE companyID = tblCompanies.Company_ID)`": `SELECT COUNT(SELECT 1 FROM tblFinishedSubContracts WHERE companyID = tblCompanies.Company_ID) FROM (((tblCompanies LEFT JOIN cargo ON (tblCompanies.PreferredCargo = cargo.Cargo_ID)) LEFT JOIN tblCTerminals ON (tblCompanies.Company_ID = tblCTerminals.companyID)) LEFT JOIN users ON tblCompanies.CompanyCEO = users.ID) WHERE tblCompanies.Company_ID = 7`  Not quite sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: @jefffan24: My fault: I left out a pair of parentheses. `COUNT(SELECT ...)` should be `COUNT((SELECT ...))` (one pair belongs to the `COUNT`, to delimit its argument; the other belongs to the subquery, to mark it as such). I've corrected my answer.

Comment: new issue: Subquery returns more than 1 row ... can count handle that type of subquery?

Comment: @jefffan24: Gah, I'm sorry, I don't know what I was thinking. I guess the SQL part of my brain turned itself off for St. Patrick's Day. :-P  I've re-edited my answer: it should be `(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ...)`, not `COUNT((SELECT 1 FROM ...))` (and not `COUNT(SELECT 1 FROM ...)`).

Comment: That worked much better, thank you so much.  I'm going to try and fix those other left joins and see what I can do :)

Comment: @jefffan24: Glad to hear it! :-)

Comment: Ok last issue (I hope)...for some reason the query is returning 14 rows (all copies of the same row) no matter what ID I use.  Even with the changes you gave for tblCTerminals (which worked perfectly btw) and the finishedContract and finishedSubContracts.  Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: yeah its really weird...got me confused :/  Its done this since the beginning.

Comment: geez...forgot to remove the tblCTerminals left join :/  removed that and it fixed the issue...

Comment: O.K., cool. I was trying to figure out where 14 came from; it seemed to violate the Law of Small Numbers. I'm glad you solved it. :-)